# extending property form outside of constructor

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have something like this:

```
interface Scope extends ng.Scope {
   getMeSome(id:string):number[];
}
export class AwesomeController {
    constructor (public $scope:Scope) {
       $scope.getMeSome = id => this.getMeSome(id);
    }
    getMeSome(id:string){
      console.log('Alright... alright... here it is'); 
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I have the same method signature in 3 different places. Of course I can cut it down a bit and do that right there - in the constructor:

```
constructor (public $scope:Scope) {
   $scope.getMeSome = id => {
      console.log('Alright... alright... here it is'); 
   };
}
```

But that will blow the constructor's body like it's on steroids (if you have tens of different methods).
So I was wondering why can't I do something like that:

```
export class AwesomeController {
   constructor (public $scope:Scope) { }

   $scope.getMeSome(id:string) { // Can't extend $scope here, although I can do that in the constructor
      console.log('Alright... alright... here it is'); 
   }
}
```

Why this doesn't work? Any suggestions to make it sexier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I can tell, in classes (unlike in modules), you're *defining* the class, not *running* the class, so you can't do any assignments in the body of the class (as opposed to method bodies). So this syntax wouldn't work:

```
export class AwesomeController {
    constructor (public $scope:Scope) {}
    $scope.getMeSome = id => {
      console.log('Alright... alright... here it is'); 
    }
}
```

You're also just defining the methods of *this* class, not of other classes, so the syntax you have above wouldn't work either, since it's mucking about with the method of a different class at the spot where you're expected to just be defining your own:

```
export class AwesomeController {
    constructor (public $scope:Scope) {}
    $scope.getMeSome(id:string) => {
      console.log('Alright... alright... here it is'); 
    }
}
```

I think you'll just have to do it one of the first two ways that you proposed - which both look just fine to me.

Comment: well, we are developers and it's natural to get arousal from seeing nice code. I thought maybe it was possible to make it nicer. However you're answer totally makes sense. Thank you.